# Rsync via remote-shell connection: server sends rsync log message rather than greeting

Tags: rsync

I am trying to run rsync via remote-shell connection from an Asustor NAS to my Ubuntu server. The command from the NAS is not possible to change since it is run from the web interface. But I know the command that is being run and I can test it manually, which gives an error. It looks something like this when I run it from the NAS:

```
$ /usr/builtin/bin/rsync -e "/usr/bin/ssh -l ssh-user-on-my-server -p 12345" --progress -a --timeout=60 rsync://rsync-user-on-my-server@myserver.com:873/rsync-module
ssh-user-on-my-server@myserver.com's password: 
rsync: server sent "2017/01/17 19:38:58 [6920] connect from xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-url-to-the-nas.com (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx)" rather than greeting
rsync error: error starting client-server protocol (code 5) at /asustor/branch2_6_2016_09_22/x64_g1/source/rsync-3.0.9/main.c(1649) [Receiver=3.0.9]
```

I happend to notice that the message above looks exactly like the log format from rsyncd. This is an example output from rsyncd when running rsync from the NAS to my Ubuntu server without SSH:

```
2017/01/06 23:42:13 [5979] connect from xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-url-to-the-nas.com (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx)
2017/01/06 22:42:13 [5979] rsync on rsync-module/ from rsync-user@xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-url-to-the-nas.com (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx)
2017/01/06 22:42:13 [5979] building file list
2017/01/06 22:42:14 [5979] sent 172 bytes  received 24 bytes  total size
```

I have verified that both SSH and rsync works on their own, this problem only happen when I try to run the script, that is rsync via remote-shell connection.

This looks a lot like [Rsync with ssh and root not working after change hosts IP](https://serverfault.com/questions/730199/rsync-with-ssh-and-root-not-working-after-change-hosts-ip), but the problem there was a greeting message from `.bashrc`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself. As I said, the output that rsync complained about looked exactly as the rsync log. The problem was my `rsyncd.conf`. I started this project by building a docker for the rsync service. To get feedback from my docker, I added the following line in my config file: `log file = /dev/stdout`. The rsync daemon printed the log directly to `stdout`!